# Saving an array of arrays to user defaults

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I can save a single array to user defaults using this:

```
var array = [0,0,0]

defaults.set(array, forKey: "SavedArray") //saves array

array = defaults.object(forKey: "SavedArray") as? [Int] ?? [Int]()
```

but it will not let me save an array of arrays, I'm trying this:

```
arrayOfArrays = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

defaults.set(arrayOfArrays, forKey: "SavedArrayOfArrays") //saves array

arrayOfArrays = [defaults.object(forKey: "SavedArrayOfArrays") as? Array<Int> ?? Array<Int>()] //loads array
```

It results in loading an empty array within an array "[[]]" and does not save the list of arrays within an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is a key mismatch. You save the array for key `SavedArrayOfArrays` but load it for `arrayOfArrays`

Second of all, the type of the nested array is `[[Int]]` or `Array<Array<Int>>`, not `[Int]` or `Array<Int>`

Finally, `UserDefaults` got a dedicated method to load arrays

```
let arrayOfArrays = defaults.array(forKey: "SavedArrayOfArrays") as? [[Int]]
```

Comment: I am getting Attempt to insert non-property list object error while adding array of array of objects in User Defaults

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal You cannot save custom classes/structs to `UserDefaults` by default.

Comment: Is there a way to do this? Like I have to save an array of structs in userDefaults

Comment: @ShivamPokhriyal That's beyond the scope of this question. Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=insert+non-property+list+object)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 arrayOfArrays = defaults.array(forKey: "arrayOfArrays") as? [[Int]]
```

or you can do this

```
arrayOfArrays = defaults.array(forKey: "arrayOfArrays") as? [Array<Int>]
```

Comment: UserDefaults has a specific method to load arrays    `defaults.array(forKey: "arrayOfArrays") as? [[Int]]`

Comment: I agree this is another option

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all!

I tried saving it with [[Int]] at the end like you all suggested, then xcode made me switch it to [[Int]])! and it worked!

```
arrayOfArrays = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

defaults.set(arrayOfArrays, forKey: "SavedArrayOfArrays") //saves array

arrayOfArrays = (defaults.array(forKey: "SavedArrayOfArrays") as? [[Int]])! //loads array
```

Comment: Instead of posting your own answer, accept one of the other answers that best solved your issue (click the checkmark to the left of the answer).